# Haskell Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda

Tags: database, haskell, lambda

I just need some help with my following code. I believe that i have created the correct lambda function to give the titles of the films a given user has rated, along with that user’s ratings.

However i seem to get an error when running the following code. The error is: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda

I have never seen this before and would love for someone to help me fix this and give me a greater understanding into how to fix it in the future.

Thanks!

```
import Data.List 
import Text.Printf

type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])


testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]),
                ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
                ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
                ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
                ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
                ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
                ("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
                ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
                ("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
                ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
                ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
                ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
                ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
                ("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
                ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
                ("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
                ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
                ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])]         



userRatedFilms :: String -> [Film]
userRatedFilms username
     = filter(\(_,_,_,[(user,_)]) -> user == username) testDatabase
```

Comment: The way you do it is that you support only films with exactly 1 rating. This is why you are being warned, because this is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Yes, i see that know, how do i use that same function because im sure it works to do it for a list of ratings? Maybe a concat to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
filter ((username `elem`) . (\(_,_,_,xs) -> map fst xs)) testDatabase
```

But note that you should *not* write functions that depend on "global variables", even not on pure ones. (Because your next question will probably be something like: I have written 982 functions that use `testDatabase`, but now I need to read the database from some file, how do I overwrite `testDatabase`?)

Another note: If you want to *combine* pattern matching and filtering, consider using list comprehension:

```
userRatedFilms films user = [ film | film@(_,_,_,[(u,_)]) <- films, u == user ]
```

This would find the films that have exactly 1 rating from `user`.

Comment: Yes, i will have that question, but i have an idea of how to go about it using I/O. 

I need it to show multiple films from the user hence the comprehension wont be needed. If i dont go about it using this lambda function i see myself writing out many functions till it carries out the solution and i just want to keep it short and simple.  

The userratedfilms you have suggested will not work with my testdatabase i believe due to different types.

I will try mapping it and see if i can get a result.

Edit// Cheers it worked.

Answer (score 0):

"Non-exhaustive patterns" means that some case "fall through".

Let's say we've got a simple lambda - `\[name] -> name==username`.
Let's convert it to a regular function:

```
f :: [String] -> Bool
f (_,[name]) = name ==username
```

That's a legal function. But what happens when we call it like this:

```
f []
```

The only pattern in the function is for a list with one element, and we call it with an empty list. So the empty list "falls through" and we get this error.

That means one of two things:

1. Maybe you'll never need another pattern, and the bug is that the function is called with an illegal argument (for example, if you know that another function should only return list with one item - so the bug may be in that function).
2. Maybe you just need to expand the function definition, like this: `\x -> case x of ...`. There's also a ghc extension called LambdaCase that supports this syntax: `\case [] -> 1; [x] ->2; ...`.

Comment: So will i need to add error handling for this empty list?

Edit: Ill try your help but doubt ill be able to figure this out. Lambda is always a tricky function for me.

Comment: Depends on the the desired behaviour of the function in this case.
For example, the standard function for getting the first item in a list, `head`, returns an error for an empty list.
Anyway, any error is better than "non-exhaustive patterns".

Comment: A lambda expression is for straightforward and simple function. If your function gets complex, use `let` or `where` and define a helper function.